# Spring JPA query the database by columns and values got from POST request body

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have about 60 very big entities, and I would like to be able to search these entities by certain columns and values that I get from JSON Request Body.

I am using **postgreSql**

I have read about specifications, but there is a lot of code to write.

As well I have found **automated specification resolver** (https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver), but it seems like it works only with params from GET request. The encoded params and values will exceed the maximum limit of chars admitted in URL

I would like to find a generic method, which will take the params from JSON and query the specified table, with minimum code needed

Do you have any suggestions/examples?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem using projections:

- See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) and [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/dto-projections/) for examples.

Instead of using `Interface` or `DTO` projections, you can directly use `Tuple` to extract data. The advantage of using `Tuple` is that you don't need to create additionnal classes. See example [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tip-best-way-scalar-projections/)